# Match interconnected arabic characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match interconnected Arabic characters to do expansion like this:

```
 بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم
```

becomes

```
بـسـم الـلـه الـرحـمـن الـرحـيـم
```

is there a way to do that using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
"بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم".replace(/(ب|ت|ث|ج|ح|خ|س|ش|ص|ض|ط|ظ|ع|غ|ف|ق|ك|ل|م|ن|ه|ي)(?=\S)/g, "$1ـ");
```

returns:

```
"بـسـم الـلـه الـرحـمـن الـرحـيـم"
```

Clarification:

We're matching letters that can be interconnected with the proceeding character by doing an OR group between all those characters, then we make sure it's not followed by a white space (not an end of word). then we replace the first matched group (the letter) by itself ($1) followed by an expansion character.

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked, can you please explain it a little bit?

Comment: Wow, definitely easier than what I came with

Comment: @user3671328, it's essentially doing what I wanted you to do manually. He is listing all the characters that can connect to the characters before and after, then replacing them with themselves ($1) in addition to ـ.

Comment: @Mzn thank you for the explanation if I knew I wouldn't have modified my answer :)

Comment: @user3671328 I modified the answer to add clarification.

Comment: It is incorrect Arabic to replace the word: "الله" with the word: "الـلـه". These are 2 different words.

Answer (score 0):

I had a project once in which I had to choose the correct unicode codes to render depending on the position of the letters; so that they appear connected (or disconnected) as appropriate, because I was using a system non-compliant with Unicode.

The unicode values for the disconnected Meem (م) is different than the one that is connected. BUT:

Unfortunately for your case, and most fortunately for many other cases, it is part of the unicode specification that displaying letters be separated from their actual unicode value. This is why you might have the unicode for a disconnected Meem, but it displayed as connected! The specification includes that comparing the connected Meem to a disconnected one always yields the correct value semantically which is true for equivalence. This makes things a lot easier!

What I ended up doing is to create a static data structure (use hard coded dictionaries or arrays) or XML or whatever. This data structure would tell us when each Arabic letter is connected or not (to both after and before).

For example:

```
//list of chars that can connect before and after
var canConnectBeforeAfter = new List<char>() { 'ع', 'ت', 'ب', 'ي' /*and so on*/ };

//list of chars that can connect only to character before them (of that character can connect to the one after it! watch out for وو)
var cannotConnectAfter = new List<char>() { 'ر', 'و' };

var cannotConnect = new List<char>() { 'ء' });
```

You will need to add the right characters for the right lists. I hope you don't have to deal with Harakat!!!!

سلام, let me know if you need clarification